# Problems after installing EWS API 2.2

Tags: exchangewebservices

i have installed the latest EWS API 2.2 on my Exchange 2016 CU9 box.
After that, the Outlook mechanism for Out-of-Office (german: Abwesenheits-Assistent) does not work anymore?!

Deinstalling the EWS API and rebooted the Server: Out-of-Office works again...

Is this a bug?
Is there any workaround for this problem?

Any help really appreciated!

Kind regads,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

There will already be a version of the EWS Managed API in the Exchange ServerV15\bin directory of Exchange (2016) so the version your installing is essentially downgrading the version on the server which is what is causing the problem.

You should just be able to use the version in the bin directory or just don't use the installer and load the assembly from the file location you copy it to.